# Every time I use wp_get_current_user() my plugin breaks

Tags: plugins, php, functions, users

I have been trying to make a sign-out plugin that allows users to sign out from military training activities that they should be at. After they fill out a form explaining why they are not going to be at an activity, they submit it, and it puts all the data into a mysql database. I am trying to save the user's id to their other data so we can tell who is signing out, but everything I have tried breaks the plugin, and gives me the white screen of death.

Thanks for your help. Here is my code to get the users id:

```
function f2user() {
// Get the current user's info 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) 
    return; 

return $current_user->ID;
}

$usersid = f2user();
$activity = $_POST['activity'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$explanation = $_POST['explanation'];
```

Comment: You need WP_DEBUG on. Otherwise it's a wild goose chase working out what's wrong. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG or https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: What means "breaks"? Do you get some errors? I so, what erros? No errors but the purpose of the function is not get? Please, explain. Also, where and when do you execute `f2user()` function? Please, show us the context of execution. I guess you are trying to use `wp_get_current_user()` outside WordPress.

Comment: I have used debug but I am only getting error from another plugin installed                        **Notice: Undefined index: page in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/thinkup-panels/thinkup-panels.php on line 6**

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong with f2user(). All I am trying to do is turn $usersid = to the user's ID number so I can save it with their form. Everything else maybe me being stupid and doing unnecessary tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
If no user are signed in then wp_get_current_user get fatal error so your plugin breaks. But if you want only user id then use get_current_user_id.
If no user signed in then it will return 0. So your plugin will not break.
Thanks

```
function f2user() {
    // Get the current user's info 
    $current_user = get_current_user_id(); 
    return $current_user;
}
$usersid = f2user();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current user ID easily using `get_current_user_id()`.

```
$usersid = get_current_user_id();
$activity = $_POST['activity'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$explanation = $_POST['explanation'];
```

For your function `f2user()` you can change your code to this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
return $current_user->ID;
```

According to [`wp_get_current_user()` doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user), if no user is signed in, `$current_user->ID` would return 0.

Comment: I have tried replacing my code with this, and I am still getting the white screen of death with only one theme error that has been around before I started the plugin, and the f2_signout page doesn't even use the theme.